# Append arguments to dsymutil in Xcode toolchain

Tags: xcode, dsym, dsymutil

Due to an issue in the Xcode toolchain, I need to append a certain argument to the call of `dsymutil`.

Is there an environment variable of user defined macro in the build settings of Xcode which appends or invokes the `dsymtutil` tool with the given arguments?

Comment: What version of Xcode? What extra argument would you give?

Comment: It's Xcode 11 and I want to add the `-verbose` flag